# Реальное применение RxSwift

Tags: swift, функциональное-программирование

Я буду очень признателен за примеры, для чего реально применяется RxSwift (в реальных проектах).
Я понимаю логику, но никаких примеров адекватнее поиска по вводимому тексту или отправки множества запросов на сервер я не встречал.

Если кто сталкивался с разумным применением RxSwift, напишите пожалуйста для чего он использовался и (самое важное!) чем это решение было лучше альтернативных. Примеры проектов и кода не обязательны, мне важно понять, для чего его использовать, как использовать, я разберусь.

Разумеется простое KVO не учитываем, оно итак есть в самом Swift.

Спасибо за любые ответы по теме.

Comment: Присоединяюсь, сам недавно задавался тем же вопросом. По факту могу сказать, что библиотека является де-факто стандартом, если вы хотите использовать архитектурный шаблон MVVM. (стандартный Swift в байндинги не умеет напрямую) Про другие примеры сам бы с удовольствием послушал.

Answer (score 1):

При runtime происходил очень много асинхронных процессов , причем работающих одновременно. 
От анимации поднятия клавиатуры до запуска проигрывателя.

Создание качественного асинхронного приложения, можно добиться и при помощи стандартных API от Notifications и заканчивая GCD.
Но реализовать действительно грамотных асинхронных подход очень сложно.

Rx упращает создание асинхронного кода.  И использует такой подход как Асинхронное программирование (тесно связанно с функциональным программированием).

К каждому эвенту в Rx надо относиться как к потоку (в этом может я и не прав).

т.е. Если вы нажали на какую нибудь кнопку, поток должен дойти до обновления данных а потом вернуться с результатом.

В целом считаю что если у вас много асинхронного кода, например чат при работе с socket, или использования сетевого протокола DDP, или с базой данных FireBase. То я бы предпочтем использовать RX с MVVM или [CleanSwift](https://github.com/Clean-Swift/CleanStore).

Если-же у вас в приложении не много асинхронного кода то предпочтительнее использовать не реактивных подход.

Comment: >"т.е. Если вы нажали на какую нибудь кнопку, поток должен дойти до обновления данных а потом вернуться с результатом". Вот тут как раз не очень понятно, чем это лучше обычного Callback?